# Can someone help me here?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native, react-hooks

Im trying to filter some type of data into 3, full history, sent, and received. Im using a useState hook, already using the set, but dont know where to use the first variable. And its printing me all the transactions.[image]

im doing a statement verifying if the transaction inside the array is none(history, received(credit), or sent(debit, and placing that into an empty array.
[image]

And here im trying to use the variable and the hook with a component that i created.

[image]

idk if i have to put something different in the 'data' prop.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I placed the 'section' in the data. and tried adding a new prop to my component, but still, it prints me all the transactions

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Can you post code as code and not images?

Comment: Please use the title to explain your *technical* problem. Describe what the issue is so people looking at a list of questions will know which they can answer.

Answer (score 1):

flatlist type should be TransactionDirection

```
<FlatList<TransactionDirection>>
```

Comment: TransactionDirection in my case is an enum, and i have other things in the flatlist which the enum doesnt have. But it was a good idea

Comment: you are pushing the enum value to temp array. so it's taking that type. you can have multiple types using `|` operator like `<TransactionDirection | Transaction>`